# Question on conjectured formulas for $B_n$, $\eta(s)$, and $\zeta(s)$

Tags: number-theory, binomial-coefficients, riemann-zeta, incompleteness, bernoulli-numbers

The $B(s)$ function defined below is the extension of the Bernoulli number function $B_n$ in the spirit of [Analytic Continuation of Bernoulli Numbers ...](https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/9705021) except the definition here follows the convention $B_1=-1/2$ instead of $B_1=1/2$ which is advocated by the referenced paper. Note $B(n)=B_n$ when n is a positive integer.

**(1)** $\quad B(s)=(-1)^{s-1}\,s\,\zeta(1-s)$

---

The following two figures illustrate the real and imaginary parts of the $B(s)$ function defined in formula (1) above. The red discrete portion of Figure (1) illustrates the evaluation of the real part of $B(s)$ defined in formula (1) where $s=n$ and n is a positive integer, and the red discrete portion of Figure (2) illustrates the evaluation of the imaginary part of $B(s)$ defined in formula (1) at integer values of $s$. Note the imaginary part of $B(s)$ always seem to evaluate to zero at negative as well as positive integers. Also note $B(0)$ as defined in formula (1) above is indeterminate but seems to converge to $B_0=1$ in a limit sense.

---

[image: Illustration of real part of B(s)]

**Figure (1):** Illustration of real part of $B(s)$

---

[image]

**Figure (2):** Illustration of imaginary part of $B(s)$

---

The following conjectured formulas are refinements of formulas defined in my three previous questions on the [Dirichlet eta function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3253496), [Riemann zeta function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3262873), and [Bernoulli number function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3341307).

**(2)** $\quad \eta(s)=\underset{m\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{1}{2^m}\sum\limits_{n=1}^m\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{m-n}\binom{m}{m-n-i}\right)$

**(3)** $\quad \zeta(s)=\underset{m\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{1}{2^m\left(1-2^{1-s}\right)}\sum\limits_{n=1}^m\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{m-n}\binom{m}{m-n-i}\right)\,,\quad s\ne 1+\frac{2\,π\,i\,k}{\log(2)}$

**(4)** $\quad B(s)=\underset{m\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{(-1)^{s-1}\,s}{2^m\,\left(1-2^s\right)}\sum\limits_{n=1}^m (-1)^{n-1} n^{s-1}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{m-n}\binom{m}{m-n-i}\right)\,,\quad s\ne \frac{2\,π\,i\,k}{\log(2)}$

---

Formulas (2), (3), and (4) above are related and a proof of any one of these would imply the correctness of all three formulas. Formulas (2), (3), and (4) above for $\eta(s)$, $\zeta(s)$ and $B(s)$ are illustrated following the questions below.

---

With respect to formula (2) above, if one defines $a(m,n)=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2^m}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{m-n} \binom{m}{m-n-i}$ then I believe $\underset{m\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(a(m,n)\right)=(-1)^{n-1}$ where smaller values of $n$ converge much faster than larger values of $n$. This explains why $\eta(s)=\underset{m\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^m\frac{a(m,n)}{n^s}\right)$ which is equivalent to formula (2) above evaluates much differently than $\eta(s)=\underset{m\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^m\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s}\right)$ which only converges for $\Re(s)>0$.

---

I've reviewed formulas for $\eta(s)$ and $\zeta(s)$ on Wikipedia and Wolfram MathWorld and haven't found any formulas similar to formulas (2) and (3) above. I believe formulas (2) and (3) evaluate exactly correct when $s$ is a non-positive integer and $|s|\le m-1$. Exact convergence at non-positive integer values at finite evaluation limits seems to be a characteristic of global (or nearly global) formulas for $\eta(s)$ and $\zeta(s)$ such as the following which seem to evaluate exactly correct when $s$ is a non-positive integer and $|s|\le K$.

**(5)** $\quad\eta(s)=\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=0}^K\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k\,\binom{n}{k}}{(k+1)^s}\right)$

**(6)** $\quad\zeta(s)=\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}}\sum\limits_{n=0}^K\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k \binom{n}{k}}{(k+1)^s}\right)\,,\quad s\ne 1+\frac{2\,π\,i\,k}{\log(2)}$

**(7)** $\quad\zeta(s)=\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{1}{s-1}\sum\limits_{n=0}^K\frac{1}{n+2}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k \binom{n}{k}}{(k+1)^s}\right)$

---

I believe formula (4) above for $B(s)$ evaluates exactly correct when $s$ is a positive integer and $s\le m$ which leads to formula (8) below for $B_n$. I've reviewed formulas for $B_n$ on Wikipedia and Wolfram MathWorld and the most similar formula I found is illustrated in formula (9) below where $\mathcal{S}_{n-1}^{(k)}$ is the [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

**(8)** $\quad B_n=\frac{(-1)^n\,n}{2^n\,\left(2^n-1\right)}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k+1}\,k^{n-1}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-k}\binom{n}{n-k-i}\,,\quad n>0$

**(9)** $\quad B_n=\frac{n}{2^n\,\left(2^n-1\right)}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^{k+1}\,k!\,2^{n-k-1}\,\mathcal{S}_{n-1}^{(k)}\,,\quad n>0$

---

My interest in the $B(s)$ function is motivated in part by the observation that formulas (8) and (9) above are somewhat similar, and it seems to me a proof of formula (8) above for $B_n$ (via a proof of the equivalence of these two formulas or some other means) might perhaps lead to a proof of formula (4) above for $B(s)$ which would also imply the correctness of formulas (2) and (3) above for $\eta(s)$ and $\zeta(s)$.

---

Formulas (8) and (9) above both evaluate correctly for $n=1$, and I believe proving the simplified relationship illustrated in formula (10) below is equivalent to proving the correctness of formula (8) above but this is the extent of my progress to date.

**(10)** $\quad\sum\limits_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k+1}\,k^{n-1}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-k} \binom{n}{n-k-i}=2^n\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{2^{k+1}}\sum\limits_{i=0}^k (-1)^i\,\binom{k}{i}\,(k-i)^{n-1},\quad n\gt 1$

---

> **Question**: Is formula (8) above for $B_n$ true, false, or an unprovable statement (an example of Gödel's incompleteness theorems)?

---

Formula (2) for $\eta(s)$ above can be rewritten as illustrated in formula (11) below. I verified formula (11) below evaluates exactly the same as formula (5) for $\eta(s)$ above (which is known to be a globally convergent formula) for the first $100$ positive integer values of $K$, so this is an encouraging result with respect to the conjectured global convergence of formulas (2) and (11).

**(11)** $\quad \eta(s)=\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{1}{2^{K+1}}\sum\limits_{n=0}^K\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)^s}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{K-n}\binom{K+1}{K-n-k}\right)$

---

The following two figures illustrate formulas (2) and (3) above for $\eta(s)$ and $\zeta(s)$ in orange overlaid on the corresponding reference functions in blue where formulas (2) and (3) are both evaluated at $m=100$. Note both formulas seem to converge for $s\in\mathbb R$.

---

[image: Illustration of formula (2) for eta(s)]

**Figure (3):** Illustration of formula (2) for $\eta(s)$

---

[image: Illustration of formula (3) for zeta(s)]

**Figure (4):** Illustration of formula (3) for $\zeta(s)$

---

The following two figures illustrate the real and imaginary parts of formula (4) above for $B(s)$ in orange overlaid on the corresponding reference function defined in formula (1) above in blue where formula (4) is evaluated at $m=100$ for both figures. The red discrete portion of the first figure below illustrates evaluation of the real part of formula (4) for $B(s)$ at positive integer values of $s$, and the red discrete portion of the second figure below illustrates evaluation of the imaginary part of formula (4) for $B(s)$ at positive and negative integer values of $s$. Note the real and imaginary parts of formula (4) both seem to converge for $s\in\mathbb R$.

---

[image: Illustration of real part of formula (4) for B(s)]

**Figure (5):** Illustration of real part of formula (4) for $B(s)$

---

[image: Illustration of imaginary part of formula (4) for B(s)]

**Figure (6):** Illustration of imaginary part of formula (4) for $B(s)$

---

The following three figures illustrate the absolute value, real part, and imaginary part of formula (3) above for $\zeta(s)$ evaluated along the critical line $s=1/2+i\,t$ in orange overlaid on the reference function in blue. Formula (3) is evaluated at $m=100$ for all three figures. The red discrete portion of each of the three figures below illustrates the evaluation of formula (3) for $\zeta(s)$ at the first $10$ non-trivial zeta zeros in the upper-half plane. I won't illustrate it here, but I'll note that formulas (2) and (4) for $\eta(s)$ and $B(s)$ also seem to converge along the critical line $s=1/2+i\,t$ in a similar manner.

---

[image: Illustration of formula (3) for |zeta(1/2+it)|]

**Figure (7):** Illustration of formula (3) for $|\zeta(1/2+i\,t)|$

---

[image: Illustration of formula (3) for Re(zeta(1/2+it))]

**Figure (8):** Illustration of formula (3) for $\Re(\zeta(1/2+i\,t))$

---

[image: Illustration of formula (3) for Im(zeta(1/2+it))]

**Figure (9):** Illustration of formula (3) for $\Im(\zeta(1/2+i\,t))$

Comment: Please use the notation $\eta(s)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k\,\binom{n}{k}}{(k+1)^s}$ and $\lim_{m \to \infty}\frac{1}{2^m}\sum\limits_{n=1}^m\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m-n+1}\binom{m}{m-n-i+1}$, yours isn't allowed. How did you come from the former to the latter. I already gave you some proofs of the first. I don't understand why you make your question so long and encumbered instead of just asking if the 2nd limit converges to $\eta(s)$ and mention that numerically it does for a few $s$.

Comment: The main point to prove those kind of formulas is to show it for absolutely convergent series then to do $M$ partial summations (using $\sum_{n =1}^N (-1)^{n+1}= \frac{1+(-1)^{N+1}}{2}$) to get an absolutely convergent series for $\eta(s),\Re(s)>-M+1$.

Comment: @reuns I didn't derive my formula from $\eta(s)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\,\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{(k+1)^s}$. Formula (2) for $\eta(s)$ in my question here was derived by evaluating formula (1) for $\eta(s)$ in my original question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3253496 with $N=0$ and then taking the limit as $m\to\infty$. This approach was motivated by the observation that my original formula seemed to evaluate exactly correct when $s$ is a non-positive integer and $|s|<m$ independent of the value of $N\ge 0$.

Comment: @reuns Assuming $\eta_m(s)=\frac{1}{2^m}\sum\limits_{n=1}^m\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m-n+1}\binom{m}{m-n-i+1}$, I'm interested in the exact correctness of $\eta(s)=\eta_m(s)$ when $s$ is a non-positive integer and $|s|<m$ (which is related to the correctness of formula (8) for $B_n$) as well as the pointwise convergence of $\eta(s)=\underset{m\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\eta_m(s)$ for $s\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @reuns  Does the approach you described imply anything about the exact correctness of $\eta(s)=\eta_m(s)$ when $s$ is a non-positive integer and $|s|<m$, or does it only imply the pointwise convergence of $\eta(s)=\underset{m\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\eta_m(s)$ for $s\in\mathbb{C}$?