# Analytic continuation of Bernoulli numbers: $B_{1/2}$?

Tags: riemann-zeta, analytic-continuation, bernoulli-numbers

$B_0$ is 1, $B_1$ is $\pm 1/2$, and so on (I'm not going to list every single Bernoulli number). The Bernoulli numbers $B_n$ are defined for every integer $n \ge 0$. But what about $B_{1/2}$? And $B_i$? How can the Bernoulli numbers be extended beyond integer terms? So far the only analytic continuation of $B_n$ I could find was $-nζ(1-n)$, but for my purposes I cannot explicitly use the zeta function like this. Thoughts?

Comment: This can be done, but as far as I am aware, only $p$-adically, as explained here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer%27s_congruence The consequences of these kinds of analytic continuations reach very deep into modern number theory

Comment: Why not use a fractional derivative and the Bernoulli number [derivative definition](https://functions.wolfram.com/IntegerFunctions/BernoulliB/09/)?

Comment: @Tyma Gaidash  How would I solve for a fractional derivative of $\frac{z}{e^z-1}$? Is there a formula?

Comment: See [Analytic Continuation of Bernoulli Numbers ...](https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/9705021) for one alternative, but for another alternative see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3345761) where I explore globally convergent formulas for $B(s)=(-1)^{s-1}\,s\,\zeta(1-s)$.

Comment: Hurwitz zeta function is the generalization of Bernoulli polynomials. Besides this, there is no other better generalization.