# Question on Difference Root representations of $\eta(2 n+1)$ and $\beta(2n)$ where $n\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: number-theory, roots, riemann-zeta, dirichlet-series, catalans-constant

I've noticed the [Dirichlet eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function) $\eta(s)$ and the [Dirichlet beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function) $\beta(s)$ can be represented by [difference roots](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DifferenceRoot.html) at odd and even positive integers respectfully. For example, consider the formulas below for a few positive integers.

---

$$\eta(3)=\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(2^{-K-1} \text{DifferenceRoot}\left[\{y,n\},\left\{\left(-3 K n^2-9 K n-7 K-n^4-5 n^3-15 n^2-25 n-16\right) y(n+1)+(n+2) \left(K n^2+4 K n+4 K-n^3-7 n^2-19 n-19\right) y(n+2)+\left(-(n+1)^3\right) (K-n) y(n)+(n+2) (n+3)^3 y(n+3)=0,y(0)=0,y(1)=2^{K+1}-1,y(2)=\frac{1}{8} \left(K-2^{K+1}+2\right)+2^{K+1}-1\right\}\right][K+1]\right)\tag{1}$$

$$\eta(5)=\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(2^{-K-1} \text{DifferenceRoot}\left[\{y,n\},\left\{\left(-5 K n^4-30 K n^3-70 K n^2-75 K n-31 K-n^6-7 n^5-30 n^4-90 n^3-165 n^2-161 n-64\right) y(n+1)+(n+2) \left(K n^4+8 K n^3+24 K n^2+32 K n+16 K-n^5-13 n^4-74 n^3-222 n^2-341 n-211\right) y(n+2)+\left(-(n+1)^5\right) (K-n) y(n)+(n+2) (n+3)^5 y(n+3)=0,y(0)=0,y(1)=2^{K+1}-1,y(2)=\frac{1}{32} \left(K-2^{K+1}+2\right)+2^{K+1}-1\right\}\right][K+1]\right)\tag{2}$$

---

$$\beta(2)=\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left((-1)^K 2^{-K-1} \text{DifferenceRoot}\left[\{y,n\},\left\{\left(4 (2 K-1) n^2-4 (K-1) K n+8 K-4 n^3-9 n-2\right) y(n+1)+\left(12 (K-1) n^2+4 K (4-3 K) n+K (4 (K-1) K+17)-4 n^3-25 n-16\right) y(n+2)+(n+2) (2 K-2 n-3)^2 y(n+3)-(K-n) (2 K-2 n+1)^2 y(n)=0,y(0)=0,y(1)=\frac{1}{(2 K+1)^2},y(2)=-\frac{K (4 K (K+2)+13)+1}{\left(1-4 K^2\right)^2}\right\}\right][K+1]\right)\tag{3}$$

$$\beta(4)=\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left((-1)^K 2^{-K-1} \text{DifferenceRoot}\left[\{y,n\},\left\{\left(8 \left(2 K \left(4 K^2+6 K+15\right)-5\right) n^2+64 K n^4-8 (4 K (3 K+1)+11) n^3-8 K (K (2 K (K+6)+27)-9) n+16 K (2 K (K (K+2)-1)+1)-16 n^5-17 n-2\right) y(n+1)+\left(16 (5 K-6) n^4-8 (20 (K-2) K+43) n^3+8 (K (4 K (5 K-12)+105)-75) n^2+8 K (K (2 (12-5 K) K-81)+124) n+K (8 K (K (2 (K-2) K+19)-49)+417)-16 n^5-497 n-160\right) y(n+2)+(n+2) (2 K-2 n-3)^4 y(n+3)-(K-n) (2 K-2 n+1)^4 y(n)=0,y(0)=0,y(1)=\frac{1}{(2 K+1)^4},y(2)=\frac{1}{(2 K+1)^4}-\frac{K+2}{(1-2 K)^4}\right\}\right][K+1]\right)\tag{4}$$

---

**Question**: Do the difference root representations provide any insight into the rationality of $\eta(2 n+1)$ (and hence $\zeta(2 n+1)$) and/or $\beta(2 n)$ (e.g. Catalan's constant $G=\beta(2)$) for $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

---

Mathematica explains difference root mathematical sequence (also known as holonomic sequence and P-recursive sequence) as follows:

> The holonomic sequence $h(k)$ defined by a DifferenceRoot function satisfies a holonomic difference equation $p_n(k)\ h(k+n)+p_{n-1}(k)\ h(k+n-1)+...+p_0(k)\ h(k)=0$ with polynomial coefficients $p_i(k)$ and initial values $h(n-1)=h_{n-1},...,h'(1)=h_1,h(0)=h_0$.

---

Also see [Holonomic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomic_function) and [P-recursive equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-recursive_equation).

---

Here's the information contained in formula (1) above in slightly different form. Note DifferenceRoot is followed by the holonomic difference equation and then three initial values $y(0)$, $y(1)$, and $y(2)$.

---

$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 \text{DifferenceRoot} \\
 \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 \left(-3 K n^2-9 K n-7 K-n^4-5 n^3-15 n^2-25 n-16\right) y(n+1)+(n+2) \left(K n^2+4 K n+4 K-n^3-7 n^2-19 n-19\right) y(n+2)+\left(-(n+1)^3\right) (K-n) y(n)+(n+2) (n+3)^3 y(n+3)=0 \\
 y(0)=0 \\
 y(1)=2^{K+1}-1 \\
 y(2)=\frac{1}{8} \left(K-2^{K+1}+2\right)+2^{K+1}-1 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)$

---

Formulas (1) to (4) above are based on the following formulas for $\eta(s)$ and $\beta(s)$ which I believe are globally convergent and are related to [formula (3) in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4087471). Formulas (1) and (2) above are equivalent to formula (5a)/(5b) below evaluated at $s=3$ and $s=5$ respectively.  Formulas (3) and (4) above are equivalent to formulas (6a)/(6b) below evaluated at $s=2$ and $s=4$ respectively.

---

$$\eta(s)=\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{1}{2^{K+1}}\sum\limits_{n=0}^K\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)^s}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{K-n} \binom{K+1}{K-n-k}\right)\tag{5a}$$

$$\eta(s)=\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{1}{2^{K+1}}\sum\limits_{n=0}^K\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)^s} \binom{K+1}{K-n}\,_2F_1(1,n-K;n+2;-1)\right)\tag{5b}$$

---

$$\beta(s)=\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{1}{2^{K+1}}\sum\limits_{n=0}^K \frac{(-1)^n}{(2 n+1)^s} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{K-n} \binom{K+1}{K-n-k}\right)\tag{6a}$$

$$\beta(s)=\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{1}{2^{K+1}}\sum\limits_{n=0}^K \frac{(-1)^n}{(2 n+1)^s} \binom{K+1}{K-n}\,_2F_1(1,n-K;n+2;-1)\right)\tag{6b}$$

---

In an attempt to provide further clarification, here's a Mathematica implementation of Catalan's constant based on (3) above

$C=\beta(2)=\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\text{Block}\left[\left\{\text{y0}=0,\text{y1}=\frac{1}{(2 K+1)^2},\text{y2}=-\frac{K (4 K (K+2)+13)+1}{\left(1-4 K^2\right)^2},\text{y3},n=0\right\},\text{While}\left[n+3<K+2,
\text{y3}=-\frac{\text{y0} (K-n) \left(-(2 K-2 n+1)^2\right)+\text{y1} \left(4 (2 K-1) n^2-4 (K-1) K n+8 K-4 n^3-9 n-2\right)+\text{y2} \left(12 (K-1) n^2+4 K (4-3 K) n+K (4 (K-1) K+17)-4 n^3-25 n-16\right)}{(n+2) (2 K-2 n-3)^2};
\text{y0}=\text{y1};\text{y1}=\text{y2};\text{y2}=\text{y3};n\text{++}\right];(-1)^K 2^{-K-1} \left(\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 \text{y1} & K=0 \\
 \text{y2} & K=1 \\
 \text{y3} & K>1 \\
\end{array}\right.\right)\right]\right)\tag{7}$

where I believe the implementation in (7) above is exactly equivalent to formulas (6a) and (6b) above evaluated at $s=2$ and when (6a), (6b), and (7) above are all three evaluated at the same non-negative integer value of $K$.

---

I believe the Mathematica implementation defined in (7) above is exactly equivalent to

$$C=\beta(2)=\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left((-1)^K\, 2^{-K-1}\, y(K,K+1)\right)\tag{8}$$

where $y(K,n)$ is defined recursively as

$$y(K,n)=$$ $$\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & n=0 \\
 \frac{1}{(2 K+1)^2} & n=1 \\
 -\frac{K (4 K (K+2)+13)+1}{\left(1-4 K^2\right)^2} & n=2 \\
 \frac{(K-n+3) y(K,n-3) (2 K-2 n+7)^2+\left(93 n+4 \left(n^3-2 (K+4) n^2+K (K+11) n-K (3 K+17)\right)-97\right) y(K,n-2)-\left(-4 n^3+12 (K+2) n^2-4 K (3 K+14) n-61 n+K (4 K (K+8)+77)+59\right) y(K,n-1)}{(2 K-2 n+3)^2 (n-1)} & n>2 \\
\end{array}\right.\tag{9}.$$

Comment: NO! Because `DifferenceRoot` is a specific function in `Mathematica` which needs to be at a minimum explained in a general mathematics context such as Math Stack Exchange, or better yet replaced with mathematical equations. Also because very long formulas give no insight.

Comment: @Somos I don't know much about difference roots and hence my question, but I provided a link to the description given by Mathematica in my question above which I believe explains the general mathematics context (see Details) as well as the Mathematica syntax for the formulas above. I assumed difference roots was a more general concept and was hoping someone more familiar than myself could address the question. Did you down-vote my question just because you don't understand difference roots? If you don't understand difference roots how can you definitively answer my question as NO?

Comment: Yes, I downvoted. You copied the `DifferenceRoot` definition. Good! It is a simple concept but NOT under the name given by Wolfram. The Mathematica expressions still need to be translated into standard mathematics notation removing the need to know anything about `DifferenceRoot`. My previous comment about very long formulas with no context giving no insight is still valid. Also, what is the source of these Mma expressions? No mention of that. How do we know they are valid?

Comment: @Somos I added more information in an attempt to improve the quality of the question. I'm not exactly sure how to write the Mathematica DifferenceRoot function as a mathematical formula so instead I illustrated formula (1) in a slightly different manner.

Comment: @Somos One of my motivations for this question is I've read Apéry's irrationality proof of $\zeta(3)$ is based on a recursive formula and I was wondering if the recursive formulas here are useful in anyway.

Comment: @Somos I believe formulas (8) and (9) above are an example of what you were looking for in terms of translation into standard mathematics notation?

Comment: Yes! That is what I was asking for. As simple as that and not that hard to write.