# Is my proof of $\eta(0)=\frac{1}{2}$ correct?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification, special-functions

Is my following proof of $\eta(0)=\frac{1}{2}$ correct?

$$\eta(0)=\lim_{s\to 0^{+}}\eta(s)=\lim_{s\to 0^{+}}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s}$$
$$=\lim_{s\to 0^{+}}\left(\lim_{x\to 1^{-}}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-x)^{n-1}}{n^s}\right)$$
$$\{\text{change the order of the limits}\}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 1^{-}}\left(\lim_{s\to 0^{+}}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-x)^{n-1}}{n^s}\right)$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 1^{-}}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-x)^{n-1}\right)$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 1^{-}}\left(\frac{1}{1+x}\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}$$

I let $s\to 0^{+}$ since $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s}$ is defined for $\Re(s)>0$ and I let $x\to 1^{-}$ since $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n$ is defined for $|x|<1$.

Thank you,

Comment: Why would it be allowed to change the order of the limits?

Comment: I don't think the series converge. If you have $\sum 1/n^s$ with some $s<1$, the sum will diverge so what allow us here to say that $\sum (-1)^{n-1}/n^s$ converges?

Comment: @tac The sum converges for $s>0$ ($\Re(s)>0$ if $s$ is a complex number).

Comment: To keep things simple, we know that $$ \zeta(0) = - \frac{1}{2} $$  And $$ \eta(s) = (1 - 2^{1-s}) \, \zeta(s) \hspace{5mm}  \cdots (1) $$  Now if I put 0 in (1) we get $$ \eta(0) = \frac{1}{2} $$

Comment: I was not asking a question, I was showing to you why your calculation isn't a proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This approach does point to a valid result, which we discussed over at [Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19410/do-abel-summation-and-zeta-summation-always-coincide): Let $a_n$ be a sequence of complex numbers such that
$$F(x):= \sum a_n x^n \ \text{and}\ Z(s) = \sum a_n n^{-s}$$
converge for $0 \leq x < 1$ and $s>0$. What can we say about the limits $\lim_{x \to 1^{-}} F(x)$ and $\lim_{s \to 0^+} Z(s)$?

The answers are

(1) It is possible that $\lim_{s \to 0^+} Z(s)$ exists but $\lim_{x \to 1^{-}} F(x)$ doesn't. An example is $a_n = n^{-1} e^{i c\log n}$ for nonzero real $c$. See [Gerald Edgar's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/22861/297).

(2) If $\lim_{x \to 1^{-}} F(x)$ exists, then so does $\lim_{s \to 0^+} Z(s)$, and they are equal. See [Brad Rogers' answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/22825/297).

The second point is the one that justifies your computation. As you can see, the proof is highly nontrivial.

Comment: Thank you David .. very helpful answer (+1).

Answer (score 4):

You need to perform an analytic extension of the Dirichlet eta function

$$\eta(s)=\lim_{N\to\infty}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{(-1)^{\,n-1}}{n^s}\right),\quad\Re(s)>0.\tag{1}$$

---

One way to do this is

$$\eta(s)=\lim_{N\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{(-1)^{\,n-1}}{n^s}+\sum_{n=1}^{N+1}\frac{(-1)^{\,n-1}}{n^s}\right)\right)$$ $$=\lim_{N\to\infty}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{(-1)^{\,n-1}}{n^s}+\frac{(-1)^{N}}{2\, (N+1)^s}\right),\quad\Re(s)>-1.\tag{2}$$

---

Formula (2) for $\eta(s)$ above converges to $\frac{1}{2}$ at $s=0$ for any integer $N\ge 0$, but only more generally converges for $Re(s)>-1$ as $N\to\infty$.

---

Figure (1) below illustrates formula (2) for $\eta(s)$ above overlaid on the blue reference function $\eta(s)$ where formula (2) is evaluated at $N=100$ (orange) and $N=100000$ (green). Note formula (2) converges closer to $s=-1$ as the evaluation limit increases.

---

[image: Illustration of formula (2) for eta(s)]

**Figure (1)**: Illustration of formula (2) for $\eta(s)$ evaluated at $N=100$ (orange) and $N=100000$ (green) overlaid on the blue reference function.

---

Figure (2) and (3) below illustrate the real and imaginary parts of formula (2) for $\eta(s)$ above in orange overlaid on the blue reference function $\eta(s)$ where both are evaluated at $s=-\frac{1}{2}+i\, t$ and where formula (2) is evaluated at $N=1000$. Note formula (2) evaluates so accurately in Figures (2) and (3) below that it essentially hides the underlying blue reference function.

---

[image: Illustration of formula (2) for Re(eta(-1/2+i t))]

**Figure (2)**: Illustration of formula (2) for $\Re\left(\eta\left(-\frac{1}{2}+i\, t\right)\right)$ in orange overlaid on the blue reference function.

---

[image: Illustration of formula (2) for Im(eta(-1/2+i t))]

**Figure (3)**: Illustration of formula (2) for $\Im\left(\eta\left(-\frac{1}{2}+i\, t\right)\right)$ in orange overlaid on the blue reference function.

---

I originally investigated iterative application of this technique of analytic extension of the Dirichlet eta function $\eta(s)$ in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3253496) which eventually lead to derivation of the conjectured globally convergent formula

$$\quad \eta(s)=\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{1}{2^{K+1}}\sum\limits_{n=0}^K\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)^s}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{K-n}\binom{K+1}{K-n-k}\right),\quad s\in\mathbb{C}\tag{3}$$

which I posted in formula (11) of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3345761) and which I believe is exactly equivalent  for all $s\in\mathbb{C}$ and all $K\in\mathbb{N}$ to the known globally convergent formula

$$\quad\eta(s)=\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=0}^K\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k\,\binom{n}{k}}{(k+1)^s}\right),\quad s\in\mathbb{C}\tag{4}$$

(see [Dirichlet eta function - Numerical algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function#Numerical_algorithms)).

---

I've believe formulas (3) and (4) for $\eta(s)$ above evaluate exactly correct when $s$ is a non-positive integer and $|s|\le K$.

---

I asked about a formal proof of the equivalence of formulas (3) and (4) above in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3347821), but no one has yet posted an answer.

---

Note formula (3) above is more efficient than formula (4) above as formula (3) moves the exponentiation operation from the inner sum over $k$ to the outer sum over $n$.

---

Mathematica likes to simplify formula (3) above as

$$\eta(s)=\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{1}{2^{K+1}} \sum\limits_{n=0}^K \frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)^s} \binom{K+1}{K-n} \, _2F_1(1,n-K;n+2;-1)\right),\quad s\in\mathbb{C}\tag{5}$$

where $_2F_1(a,b;c;z)$ is a [hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function), but user [agno](https://mathoverflow.net/users/12489/agno) pointed out in a comment on my [related Math Overflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/425056) that formula (3) above can also be simplified as

$$\eta(s)=\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{1}{2^{K+1}} \sum\limits_{n=0}^K \frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)^s}\, P_{K-n}^{(n+1,-K-1)}(3)\right),\quad s\in\mathbb{C}\tag{6}$$

where $P_n^{(\alpha,\beta)}(x)$ is the [Jacobi Polynomial](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiPolynomial.html).

Comment: My answer is right based on David's answer

Comment: @AliShadhar From what I understand, the proof of $\eta(0)=\frac{1}{2}=\underset{s\to 0^+}{\text{lim}}\left(\underset{{N\to\infty}}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\frac{(-1)^{\,n-1}}{n^s}\right)\right)$ follows from the proof of $f(1)=\frac{1}{2}=\underset{x\to 1^-}{\text{lim}}\left(\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N (-1)^{\,n-1}\, x^n\right)\right)$ where the analytic continuation of $f(x)$ is $\frac{x}{x+1}$.

Comment: @AliShadhar You used $g(1)=\frac{1}{2}=\underset{x\to 1^-}{\text{lim}}\left(\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N (-x)^{\,n-1}\right)\right)$ which has the analytic continuation $\frac{1}{x+1}$ rather than f(x).

Comment: Thank you Steven

Comment: @AliShadhar As I understand it, you used the analytic continuation of the Maclaurin series for $g(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}$ as $x\to 1^-$ to derive the analytic continuation of the Dirichlet series for $\eta(s)$ as $s\to 0^+$. I believe the techniques illustrated in my answer above to extend the convergence of the Dirichlet series for $\eta(s)$ from $\Re(s)>0$ to $s\in\mathbb{C}$ can also be used to extend the convergence of the Maclaurin series for $f(x)=\frac{x}{x+1}$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}$ from $|x|<1$ to $\Re(x)>-1$. See my related question at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4652009.

Answer (score 1):

For $|x|<1$ no problem to say that
$$(1+x)\sum_{n\ge 1} (-x)^{n-1} n^{-s} =1 +\sum_{n\ge 2} (-x)^{n-1} (n^{-s}-(n-1)^{-s})$$
$$(1+x)^2\sum_{n\ge 1} (-x)^{n-1} n^{-s} =1+x-2^{-s}x+\sum_{n\ge 3} (-x)^{n-1} (n^{-s}-2(n-1)^{-s}+(n-2)^{-s})$$

The point is that the latter series converges absolutely and uniformly for $s\in [0,1], x\in [0, 1]$. So we **can change the order of limits** and obtain that

$$4\eta(0)=\lim_{s\to 0^+}\lim_{x\to 1^-} (1+x)^2\sum_{n\ge 1} (-x)^{n-1} n^{-s}=
\lim_{x\to 1^-}\lim_{s\to 0^+} (1+x)^2\sum_{n\ge 1} (-x)^{n-1} n^{-s}$$ $$=
\lim_{x\to 1^-} (1+x)^2\sum_{n\ge 1} (-x)^{n-1}=\lim_{x\to 1^-}\frac{(1+x)^2}{1+x} = 2$$